# How to stop classifying after first Correct Image Detection using tensorflow lite Android API

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera, tensorflow-lite

I am referring to the examples from google for tensorflow lite image detection. : https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection

The callback when the camera is open : onImageAvailable() calls the processImage() which calls the pane with detected object and thier confidence.
If the camer remains open it will keep classifying the object.
Is there a way to stop classifying once first successfull image detetection has happened?
All i can think of is to press the back button once first image is detected or stop the camera preview.
Any other suggestion?
If there is some method from tensorflow lite like stop Classification() , it may work

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, it runs classification whenever new image is capture.

If you want to capture only single image, you'd better use captureSession.capture() instead of captureSession.setRepeatingRequest()
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/CameraConnectionFragment.java

Please refer the CameraCaptureSession API doc.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession